# Linear maps for which $f^{-1}=f$

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

I could not find a particular name for linear maps which are their own inverse. Is there a special name for them?

Comment: Note: this is the same as saying that $f^2$ is the identity transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the term linear maps and the [linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) tag suggest that you're asking about linear transformations, i.e., maps $T : V \to W$, where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces.

Recall that every such linear transformation can be represented by some matrix $A$.

So asking if there is a $T : V \to W$ such that $T = T^{-1}$ is the same as asking if there's some matrix $A$ such that $A = A^{-1}$.  Such matrices are known as [involutory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix).

I'm not entirely sure if the word "involutory" is also used to describe $T$.

Answer (score 3):

Those linear maps are [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).

Comment: Sometimes, linear involutions are called reflections.  Often, "reflection" is reserved for the self-adjoint involutions.